Visual Studio 2022 Preview Version 17.12.0 hangs when the auto generated Blazor Web App runs in debug mode
toady (Aug 20,2024) I updated my Visual Studio 2022 both stable and preview versions 17.11.0 and 17.12.0 Preview 1 respectively by running the Visual Studio Installer and choosing both to be updated.  After the update, I created a new Blazor Web app with .NET 9 latest preview in my VS 2022 Preview and without making any modifications at all to the project, I simply clicked the debug button.  I could see the IDE building the solution and starting the debug process, my Chrome browser started up but with a blank page and simply hangs there for ever.  I had to stop the process, close Visual studio and restarted it. When I run the same project without debugging, it runs fine.  I also tried with my Visual Studio 2022 Community Version 17.11.0 (stable).  Though it was slow to start the Blazor app in debug mode, it did eventually started.  It does not have a problem running it in non-debug mode either.  What gives? Any idea anyone?  This never happened to me before.
I am running Windows 11 with all updates.  My machine has 64gb RAM, 2TB NVMe storage and a Ryzen 7 processor.

I’m encountering a problem with Visual Studio 2022 Preview Version 17.12.0. Whenever I use Ctrl + T to search in the solution, the IDE crashes immediately after I start typing. This issue started happening after I updated to the latest preview version today.

Version 17.12.0 Preview 1.0 is buggy as hell. It locks files it builds during debug with Blazor WASM and .Net 9 when using Chrome making it useless for development with that combo. The auto-suggest is getting worse. It locks suggestion on the screen even after moving the cursor. Only closing the file and reopening gets rid of it. Not sure why this version is so damn buggy. Maybe they used AI to code it.

Based on my test, i am able to reproduce the same issue in VS17.12.0 Preview 1 at my side. It seems a product issue with Blazor WebAssembly debugging.
I suggest you create a ticket to report this issue on Visual Studio Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect detailed information and do further investigation.
